# Is it bad practice to have an ajax call inside of a jQuery validation method? Or, better approach?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

Our app is using ASP.NET MVC 3 and I wanted to take advantage of creating a custom validation attribute that worked on both the client and server side.

The user will enter a physician number in an input field. The value is then used to check and see if the physician number entered is actually valid. This requires a call to the database. I have an ajax call inside my validation method. This works fine but only when async is set to false.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        onkeyup: false,
        onclick: false,
        focusInvalid: false
    })

    $.validator.addMethod('physician', function (value, element, params) 
    {
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Content("~/patient/GetPhysicianById")",
            data: { physicianNumber: value },
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function(xjhr, settings) {                                                                            
                var siblings = $(element).siblings('.physician-response');                    
                //$(siblings[0]).html("<img src=\"/content/images/ajax-loader.gif\" />");            
            }                
        });

        console.log(request);            

        if(request.responseText == "0")
            return false;

        return true;
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('physician', ['param1', 'param2'], function (options) {
        options.rules['physician'] = options.params;
        options.messages['physician'] = options.message;
    });

</script>
```

On the form, there are three different physician inputs that will trigger this method. Every time blur is lost, it runs these calls again. Also runs when the user clicks save. I'm not certain if this is really the proper approach, or I should handle this validation in a separate manner.

Comment: The only part of that that i would consider bad practice is the `async: false`, though without modifications to the validation plugin, it can't work without it.

Comment: I think there's a built-in method for just this type of validation, see here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options

Comment: @kevinB - I found out quickly that without `async: false` it wouldn't work. I'm not a fan of that either. I wonder if I'm better off creating my own call and not using this validation plug-in.

Comment: Use the remote option, this is what it is made for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at the [`[Remote]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) attribute to perform this kind of validation.

Answer (score 0):

The most common practice is to have more strict validation on the server than on the client.

So an zipcode is validated against a regex on the client, but checked against a zipcode service from the server. Or something like that. The reason for this is that most common errors can be fixed without server roundtrips, but if you go around it is nice to make sure the user didn't make any mistake that needs revisiting later.

Whether this is a good practice for your case is up to you.